# What happen If I remove all apple certificate, profile?

Tags: xcode

I have some trouble with Xcode11, and anual renew certificates. So I'm lot of lost and have no response about my trouble.
So I add a new question, perhaps more simple:

What happen if I remove ALL trace of certificate, profile, if I clean all. Can it affect my current production app, or can i still update ?

I suspect conflict from lot of certificate test, but no other idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you go to the developer center and revoke/delete all certificates and profiles. And on your computer you delete all certificates from your Keychain, and you delete all profiles from the MobileDevice folder.

Then if you have an app on the App Store, it will continue to work; users can still download it. But you will not be able to submit any updates to it and you will not be able to run any projects on a device.

You could then fix that by obtaining new certificates and profiles, which you can probably do automatically; in fact, if you *try* to run a project on a device, it will likely all happen automatically.